# If $x,y,z,t\geq 0,$ Then $\max(xy+yz+zt)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, optimization, maxima-minima

> If $x,y,z,t\geq 0$ and $x+y+z+t=1\;,$ Then $\max$ value of $(xy+yz+zt)$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write $x+y+z+t=(x+z)+(y+t)\geq 2(x+z)(y+t)$

and equality hold when $x+z=y+t$. So we get $\displaystyle x+z=y+t=\frac{1}{2}$

So we get $$\displaystyle (x+z)(y+t)\leq \frac{1}{4}\Rightarrow xy+yz+zt+xt\leq \frac{1}{4}$$

Now how can i solve it after that, help required, Thanks

Comment: I am unable to type up an answer at the moment, but this just requires a standard application of Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Thanks  Will Fisher , I aslo tried using Multiplier theorem and getting $a=d=0$ and $\displaystyle b=c = \frac{1}{2}.$ So get $\displaystyle \max(ab+bc+cd) = \frac{1}{4},$ I am looking for Inequality Solution.

Comment: Yo can finish off by noting $xy+yz+zt \leqslant \frac14-xt \leqslant \frac14$. As equality is possible, you have the maximum you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $(x+y+z+t)^2-4(xy+yz+zt)=(x-y+z-t)^2+4xt\geq0$

and the equality occurs for example, for $x=y$ and $t=z=0$.